# Django bulk update db table using model from html table 'dict' object has no attribute

Tags: python, html, sql-server, django

MODEL

```
class BGD(models.Model): #need to update name
    # id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Workgroup = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Center = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    InsertDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False)
    Is_Active = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return "%s" % (self.id)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table="table"
```

View

```
def Control_Bidding_Groups (request):
    
    B_G_Results=BGD.objects.all()
   
    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = request.POST.dict()
        data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)
        print('//////',data)
        for i in data.B_G_Results():
            print('???',i)
            obj = Bidding_Group_Description.objects.get(id=i[0].split("_")[1])
            print('55',obj)
            # Bidding_Group_Description.objects.filter(id=id).update(Is_Active)

            if not str(obj.Is_Active) == str(i[1]): #here check int or char datatype since 1 not equal "1"
                obj.Is_Active = i[1] 
                print(obj.Is_Active)
                obj.save()

        return render(request, "Control_Bidding_Groups.html", { "B_G_Results": B_G_Results})
    
    else:
        
        return render(request, "Control_Bidding_Groups.html", { "B_G_Results": B_G_Results}) #, "edit": edit
```

HTML

```
<section id="golf">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mainbg padding-all-zero">
            <div class="row panelBg">

                <label class="parav" for="ddlSubmit">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" value="Insert Records"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"
                            style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Submit</button>
                </label>

                <table class="table table-striped" width="100%">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Workgroup</th>
                            <th>Center</th>
                            <th>Bidding Group Description</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Is Active</th>

                            <th>Is Active</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="ui-sortable">

                        {% for d in B_G_Results%}
                        <tr>
                          
                            <td>{{d.Workgroup}}</td>
                            <td>{{d.Center}}</td>
                            <td>{{d.Description}}</td>
                            <td>{{d.Is_Active}}</td>
                            <td><input type="text" value="{{d.Is_Active}}" name="d_{{d.id}}"> </td>
                         </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

ERROR
'dict' object has no attribute 'B_G_Results'

data
{'17': '17',
'18': '18',
'19': '19',
'74': '74',
'75': '75',
'76': '76',
'77': '77',
'78': '78',
'79': '79',
'80': '80',
'81': '81',
'82': '82',
'83': '83',
'84': '84',
'85': '85',
'86': '86',
'87': '87',
'88': '88',
'89': '89',
'Yes, NO': 'Yes, NO',
'd_17': 'active',
'd_18': 'deactive',
'd_19': 'deactive',
'd_74': 'deactive',
'd_75': 'active',
'd_76': 'active',
'd_77': 'off',
'd_78': 'off',
'd_79': 'off',
'd_80': 'off',
'd_81': 'off',
'd_82': 'off',
'd_83': 'off',
'd_84': 'off',
'd_85': 'off',
'd_86': 'off',
'd_87': 'off',
'd_88': 'off',
'd_89': 'on',
'off': 'off',
'on': 'on'}

Comment: I am very new at Django and trying to figure out how to pass the id : '17' to update Is_Active = yes or no in the database. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

B_G_Results=BGM.objects.all(), but your model is called class BGD(models.Model)?

Comment: Still same issue good catch